# Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: \ng2-admin\node_modules\bootstrap-loader at Error (native)

Tags: angular2-routing, ng2-bootstrap

I have clone ng2-admin directory from git hub few days back and run npm install after that i am able to run and see the UI, now I had been deleted node_modules folder, docs folder, and dist folder from ng2-admin now facing below error in browser console with scattered UI.

So how to fix below error,
`

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\bootstrap-loader
    at Error (native)
    at D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:51:26
    at Error (native)
    at D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:51:26
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/index.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/index.js?sourceMap!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js (http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:56497:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:54:30)
    at Object../node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/index.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/index.js?sourceMap!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js (http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:88168:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:54:30)
    at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js (http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:52755:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:54:30)
    at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js (http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:52782:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:54:30)
    at Object../src/vendor.browser.ts (http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:90058:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:54:30)
    at Object.5 (http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:90087:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:54:30)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:5000/assets/polyfills.bundle.js:25:23)
    at http://localhost:5000/assets/vendor.bundle.js:2:1
./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/index.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/index.js?sourceMap!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js @ util.js:164
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:52
./node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/index.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/index.js?sourceMap!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js @ no-op.js?6a4c:4
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:52
./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js @ no-op.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:52
./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js @ loader.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:52
./src/vendor.browser.ts @ vendor.browser.ts:24
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:52
5 @ src async:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:52
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 7cfd64b…:23
(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:2
lang.js:134 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
client:38 [WDS] Errors while compiling.
client:80 ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\bootstrap-loader
    at Error (native)
    at D:\Client2\ng2-admin\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:51:26
 @ ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js 4:14-193
 @ ./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader`  /no-op.js`
 @ ./~/bootstrap-loader/loader.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi vendor

`
```

Comment: Looks like files are missing (as you write about deleting some modules/folders). What about restoring them, and trying again?

Comment: i have run npm install and again run npm update command, then npm start under ng2-admin path and now facing above issue, i think after deleting node_modules folder, npm install command tries to update libraries but don't know where it fails?

Answer (score 39):

The solution is very simple. You need to add a file on your project root directory:

```
postcss.config.js
```

Inside, the content can be:

```
module.exports = {}
```

<sub>This is a translated version of a now-deleted non-English answer by [Feng SHADU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444862/feng-shadu).</sub>

Comment: I have same problem, and this solution works.
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues/604#issuecomment-271974780

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add another file, it's enough to add your options in your webpack config:

```
         {
           loader: `postcss-loader`,
           options: {
             options: {},
             plugins: () => {
               autoprefixer({ browsers: [ 'last 2 versions' ] });
             }
           }
         },
```

Comment: Yup, so many of these libs require extra files, I find it can be clearer to just do some things inline like this. And be sure to add `const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');` at the top of your file, plus `npm i -D autoprefixer` to install it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually to properly reference the config file in the loader options like this (create an empty one if you don't have it yet, though):

```
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        config: { 
          path: 'path/to/postcss.config.js' 
        } 
      }
    }
```

You are not supposed to create empty or dummy placeholder configs in the node_modules folders.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a reference error, more specifically an import for CSS file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Create node_modules/bootstrap-loader/postcss.config.js with the contents module.exports={};